# How do I prevent the deletion of rows in a Google spreadsheet that gets values from a different sheet with the IMPORTRANGE formula?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that pulls data from a different sheet using the IMPORTRANGE formula. It gets updated with new values as they are added to the other sheet, but I would like to prevent the deletion of values when they are deleted from the other sheet, and keep the data as is, no matter how the other sheet is edited.

Is there a different formula that does this?

Comment: Hi. You say "deletion of values" - would you please explain EXACTLY what you mean by this? - delete a row, editing of a cell substituting one value for another, etc? Would you please also provide information about the other sheet and your relationship with it. For example, how often are values edited on the other sheet, how often are values deleted? Does each row of data have a unique code. How many rows/columns of data are retrieved? Do you have control the other sheet, could you run a script/trigger on the other sheet? Regarding your sheet, how many hours in each day is your sheet open?

Comment: @Tedinoz There are two sheets which I have full control over. Sheet A was generated from form responses, and is continuing to get responses frequently. Sheet B was created to pull some data from sheet A for certain automations. Sheet A is shared with some people who have editing rights, and might accidentally delete or edit certain rows. I need to make sure that if something is deleted/edited by mistake in sheet A, the data will stay intact in sheet B. But at the same time, sheet A will continue to populate sheet B when new responses are added. 
Sheet B has an IMPORTRANGE formula and a script

Comment: @Tedinoz I did my best to squeeze all the info in 600 characters  Let me know if you need more info. And Happy New Year

Comment: OK, that's pretty important information that you might have put in your question. Particularly "Sheet A was generated from form responses... is shared with some people who have editing rights, and might accidentally delete or edit certain rows". Why not protect the responses sheet?

Comment: OK. May I suggest that your actual problem is not with `IMPORTRANGE`, and that the "real" problem is how to protect the Form Responses "Sheet A" from accidental edits. Does that sound correct to you? If so, I'd suggest a new question/research.

Comment: @Tedinoz It seems that there's no other option. Thank you for your help.